# .htaccess to web.config php issue

Tags: php, xhtml, web-config

I've been hitting these boards and I'm not really finding a solution.  My students redesigned a website for a non-profit rescue group and honestly, programming is not my forte, as much as coding is.

Website: http://www.adoptarpo.org/ 
Using a single stats.php file to allow for easy editing of a single file to show and update on all webpages, reflecting the changing numbers of adoptions.

Test server is Linux, so running an .htaccess file with the following:
Options -Indexes
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

The following is the first line of code before the HTML for the index.html, located [here](http://arpo.frightmanor.net/):  `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';?>`

Further down on the index.html file, I have the following: `<?php include("stats.php");?>`

In configuring the web.config file, the other hosting provider (who only uses Windows webservers), uploaded the following to the root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>`
```

This does not resolve the problem of pulling the data from stats.php.  It doesn't make a difference if I remove `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';?>` from the first line of the .html file or not.

Now, when I insert the following, into the web.config file, all hell breaks loose and I get following when going to www.adoptarpo.org :  The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, but for the life of me, I'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: http://www.adoptarpo.org/stats.php shows the statistics just fine. If all you want is to show this in the now empty Stats field on your page I am not sure you are looking in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these three lines to your .htaccess file.

```
<Files index.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  The webhosting netadmin was able to setup the web.config file correctly.  Thanks!